# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'list'

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

I have a series of **numpy arrays** that look like this:

```
mean_fall_1 = [np.nanmean(zero_to_nan(d)) for d in fall_1_gpa]
stdev_fall_1 = [np.nanstd(zero_to_nan(d)) for d in fall_1_gpa]
```

and a **list** which is called combination_fall_1.
And I do not know if these are needed to be shown, but I have these also:

```
def zero_to_nan(d):
    array = np.array(d)
    array[array == 0] = np.NaN
    return array

fall_1_gpa = [[mean(sub_list) for sub_list in list] for list in fall1_grades]
```

What I am trying to do is to find the best combination of mean and stdev but at the same time change the order of combination_fall_1 based on how these 2 change. What I did is the following:

```
mean_fall_1, stdev_fall_1, combination_fall_1 = sorted(list(zip(*(zip(mean_fall_1, stdev_fall_1, combination_fall_1)))))
mean_fall_1, stdev_fall_1, combination_fall_1 = (list(t) for t in sorted(list(zip(*(zip(mean_fall_1, stdev_fall_1, combination_fall_1))))))
```

where I am trying to sort them and since it is with zip I am trying to unzip them afterwards. 
I am new to this and I did not know that I cannot compare a list with an numpy array and I get this error:
mean_fall_1, stdev_fall_1, combination_fall_1 = sorted(

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and
>   'list'

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: convert `list` to `numpy array`

Comment: but will i then be able to do mean_fall_1, stdev_fall_1, combination_fall_1 = sorted(list(zip(*(zip(mean_fall_1, stdev_fall_1, combination_fall_1))))) ? i am sorry if this sounds not that smart but i am really new to this. since this sorts lists as far as i know. maybe it is smarter to convert numpy array to list?@furas

Comment: you may convert `numpy array` to `list` if it helps.

Comment: I am doing this:     mean_fall_1_list = list(mean_fall_1)
since it contains float values and still gives me same error even though I converted everything. Why? @furas

Comment: do you converted list `mean_fall_1_list` in line which makes problem `sorted(....)` ?  Problem can makes also other lists which you use in `sorted()` so you may have to convert all of them before use in sorted.